# Can Teamcity select agents by regex matching build parameter value?

Tags: teamcity

I have a number of Teamcity Agents, some in a remote location.

Both locations have a default app server instance to test clients against, but we also have some experimental app servers that only run here.

Developers wanting an experimental server set the build parameter `experimental.server=SOMETHING` to tell the test script to use that. The trouble is, they also have to select the local build pool to get a local agent in the `Run...` dialogue, and that's easy to forget (which is why creating a full set of duplicate build types doesn't work either).

Is there a way to set an Agent Requirement on the buildtypes to send tests wanting experimental servers only to local agents?

I know builds can have requirements for JAVA=1.7 or JAVA=.* to select those with the right, or with any, SDK.

But it seems like I need to set a remote agent's property to '^$' and a local agent's property to '.*', and make Teamcity only use remote agents if the build property `experimental.server` matches the regex in the agent's `supported.experiments` property.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-66331

Jetbrains replied:

> I'm afraid it's not possible: agents are selected for certain build
>   configurations and not vice versa. On agents requirements page of a
>   build configuration, you can define requirements an agent should meet
>   to run the particular build configuration. You can, however, assign
>   projects to agent pools.
>
> In your case, you can create a subproject
>   that inherits all the required build templates and just assign this
>   project to your experimental agent pool.
>
> That said, don't hesitate
>   to submit a new feature request on our public bug tracker and ask for
>   the feature you want to see.
>
> Best regards